# AngularJS UI Grid cell template using TYPESCRIPT

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

**Before you answer my question please consider that I am using AngularJS 1 with TYPESCRIPT.**

Does any body know how to bind a controller function to cell template like asked in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/_gsXkagIuRQ) using [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/)?

I have got a very similar situation, where I define custom cell template containing buttons and try to bind the `ng-click` directive to a function in the controller?

So I just have something like this:

Component template:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions" class="grid" external-scopes="ctrl"></div>
```

Component controller (just some code snippets):

```
ctrl = this;

exampleFunction() {
    console.log("Example function called.");
}

actionsCellTemplate = 
            '<btn class="btn btn-default action-button" ng-click="getExternalScopes().exampleFunction()">' +
                '<i class="icon-blue"><b>...</b></i>' +
            '</btn>';

columnDefs: [ { displayName: '', field: 'actions', enableColumnMenu: false, cellTemplate: this.actionsCellTemplate } ]
```

I **DO NOT** get any errors in the browser console.

Comment: is `exampleFunction()` part of the `scope`? Or is it just defined inside controller? Also, have you tried `ng-click="grid.appScope.exempleFunction()"`?

Comment: I don't use scope at all. just write my fields and methods in controller and access them using `$ctrl.` syntax in the html template -> what works pretty well. The `grid.appScope.exempleFunction()` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External scopes are no longer supported in ui-grid since RC 19.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes

> getExternalScopes() function is removed. Use grid.appScope instead. external-scopes attribute is removed. Use gridOptions.appScopeProvider to assign values other than $scope.$parent to appScope